# How does paging on a web page work?

Tags: database, web-applications, paging

What are the principles or implementation involved in making a result set from a database "pageable" ?

How is it possible to page over a million records without storing it in memory? What allows "jumping" from 5 to the 50th page number when there are 100 pages ?

I'm looking for a pseudo-code kind of explanation on how the paging is accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic premise is to remember the following:

1. Define your page size i.e the number of records per page (`PAGE_SIZE`)
2. Know the total number of records in the set. Then you can calculate how many pages there are. `var numPages = totalNumRecords / PAGE_SIZE;`
3. Use a variable to track the page number i.e `Page = 1`
4. Perform a simple Skip/Take algorithm shown below and you have the elements needed to page

`Skip((page - 1)*PAGE_SIZE).Take(PAGE_SIZE);`

So what will happen is when you hit the data source for results, you will skip to the set of records you want and take the prescribed amount. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Ah. Makes sense. I guess where I was going with my thought process was that how efficient it is at the database level to "skip and take", but I neglected to mention that in the question. I suppose the database is smart!

Comment: This can still easily be done in a database using a set-based approach. So it can still be highly efficient. You have to setup your query to receive a skip and take value based on the algorithm I supplied then use `SQL` to get the results

Answer (score 2):

typically there is something in the URL of the Next button that modifie the database query that renders the page. Then that rendered page bumps the index in the next URL.

So page one might be a SQL request that has LIMIT 20, page 2 also has LIMIT 20 but also OFFSET 20.

So basically only 20 items are loaded at a time in that model, but the page also loads how many items have been offset so fat and changes the "Next Page" URL.

Typically there will also be a function that checks where you are relative to the total item count so the page knows if it should show a next link or not.